# Ruby PATH nightmare on Windows -- PATH variable not working

Tags: ruby, windows, path

This is a nightmare.  I installed a new version of Ruby 2.5 using the Ruby Windows installer (located here:  https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ ). This is the version:  `Ruby interpreter (CUI) 2.5.3p105 [x64-mingw32]`

I presumed that the new Windows installer would add `"C:\Ruby25-x64\bin"` to my PATH, WHICH IT DID.

But the command line indicates that my computer is STILL USING the EARLIER 2.2.4 Ruby version that I had previously installed.  Both DOS AND GITBASH show the earlier Ruby version (even after I add the NEW ruby path to both the USER and the SYSTEM PATH environment variables and even after reboot!).

In other words, it looks like RUBY is NOT using the PATH variable AT ALL on my machine, since changing PATH to point to the newer version HAS NO EFFECT.

I notice that there's a difference between MING64 and MING32 in the output.
I have a 64 bit machine, but I presume that that has nothing to do with use of the PATH variable.

```
USER@USER MINGW64 /
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
```

The registry also has the newest ruby path listed (PATH is stored in the registry).

Why is Windows not recognizing the new Ruby and insisting on using the old one?

Comment: You may need to note the **sequence** of PATH variable? That means, you append the new path to the **end** of PATH, or to the **head** of PATH? This may differ.

Comment: Check again your PATH variable, maybe it has the older path before the new path.  Also it's better to remove the old version given you don't need it anymore. Please try to calm down.

Comment: Your screaming caps are annoying and demeaning of readers.

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` variable is used for "search" executables. If the required executable with given name found, then the system will use it, and ignore the rest.

You may have a `bin` of previous version of Ruby listed in `PATH` variable before, then if you append your new version of Ruby at the **end** of `PATH`, it may be ignored due to the hit of previous found, old version of Ruby.

To make sure you can use the new version of Ruby listed in the `PATH` variable, just remove the old version from `PATH`, or move the new version to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Yes . . . Geno Chen was correct.  I had an Instance of Ruby connected to a Ruby on Rails installation.  Here's what I discovered.

Okay, here's the issue.  I had installed BOTH Ruby 
and Ruby on Rails on the Windows laptop.  Both are 
Windows installers.  The problem is that Ruby on 
Rails installs its OWN instance of Ruby that 
HIJACKS the Ruby path by some EVIL means other 
than the PATH environment variable.  In order to 
get my recently installed Ruby 2.5 version to 
work, I had to UNINSTALL the older Ruby on Rails 
version that was using Ruby 2.2.

Does anyone have a clue what this EVIL hijack 
consists of?

I now no longer have Rails, unless I use the 
newest rails installer.  I do not desperately need 
it; I was just learning rails for the sake of 
exploring it at one point.

However, there really OUGHT to be a way to install 
rails WITHOUT installing its version of the Ruby 
engine?  A way to get Rails to use the current 
Ruby that is globally installed on one's computer.

Barring that, I guess one would need some sort of 
Ruby version manager to switch paths.  The version 
manager would have to use whatever hijack method 
Rails uses to switch paths, I guess.

Comment: I think you should 1. give the evidence of this hijack (full content of `PATH` variable, command running result, etc.) 2. use a BETTER word or tone.